# Sending files to bot progammatically through WebChat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I've inserted the webchat in a webview to display the bot in an android application and I want the users to send pictures taken with the camera to the bot.

The problem is that the default button to attach files opens the explorer instead of the camera, so I implemented a button to launch the camera and now I need to send the picture taken to the bot programmatically.

I've managed to send text to the bot using my own version of a Web Chat store:

```
store = window.WebChat.createStore();
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: json.token }),
store
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
document.querySelector('#cameraButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    store.dispatch({
        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
        payload: { text: "some text" }
    });
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

[EDIT] I've seen something similar for files in [WebChat's code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/core/src/actions/sendFiles.js), but I am not sure If it can be used and how:

```
const SEND_FILES = 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_FILES';

export default function sendFiles(files) {
  return {
    type: SEND_FILES,
    payload: { files }
  };
}

export { SEND_FILES };
```

Comment: You can probably encode your picture as a base64 string and post it as text in the payload.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, it send the base64 as plain text to the webchat. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No I wasn't, still stuck in the same place